How to Efficiently Load Large JSON Data into ObservableCollection in .NET MAUI?
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application where I need to load a large volume of data from a JSON file and add it to an ObservableCollection. Currently, the application becomes unresponsive during this operation, and the process is slow.
[ObservableProperty]private ObservableCollection<TaskMang> tasks;

private async Task LoadTasksFromExcel(){
var filepath = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\excel_to_json.json";

if (!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    return;
}

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

try
{
    var jsonString = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filepath);
    var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
    var root = jsonDocument.RootElement;

    if (root.TryGetProperty("Task_Master", out JsonElement taskArray))
    {
        // Use IEnumerable for lazy loading
        var tasksEnumerable = taskArray.EnumerateArray().Select(task => new TaskMang
        {
            id = task.GetProperty("TASK_ID").GetInt32(),
            TaskName = task.GetProperty("TASK_NAME").GetString(),
            TaskStartTime = task.GetProperty("START_TIME").GetString(),
            TaskEndTime = task.GetProperty("END_TIME").GetString(),
            TaskTimeTaken = task.GetProperty("TIME_TAKEN").GetString(),
            ProjectName = task.GetProperty("PROJECT_NAME").GetString(),
            SelectedProject = _projectDetailsViewModel.Projects
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectName == task.GetProperty("PROJECT_NAME").GetString())
        }).ToList();

        // Add tasks to ObservableCollection in smaller batches
        const int batchSize = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < tasksEnumerable.Count; i += batchSize)
        {
            var batch = tasksEnumerable.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                foreach (var task in batch)
                {
                    Tasks.Add(task);
                }
            });

            await Task.Delay(10); // Small delay to prevent UI freeze
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
finally
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}}

Performance: The application becomes unresponsive during data loading.
UI Freezes: Even with batching and small delays, the UI still experiences freezing.
I tried :
Batch Updates: Adding items in smaller batches with a delay.
Lazy Loading: Using IEnumerable for processing data
Questions:
Are there more efficient ways to handle large datasets in an ObservableCollection?
Is there a better approach to avoid UI freezes when adding a large number of items?
Any tips for optimizing JSON data processing in .NET MAUI?

Try loading data in the background and then load them into the Collection as batches...

use an ObservableRangeCollection it will allow you to bulk add items without firing a CollectionChanged event for each item

@FreakyAli I tried above code , i used Task.Run as well but when application starts iam loading data from json to collection, but still if its batch its not working.

@Jason i changed the observablecollection to ObservableRangeCollection and when the application starts the collection from json loads to ObservableRangeCollection but still its white screen without UI

are you positive the problem is in building the collection, and not (at least partially) in processing the json?

@Jason yes , iam sure because i tried removing the code of adding the data to observable collection, when i do that the application is smooth and start immediately. but when i use the code Observablecollectionobjectname.Add(object) the application is stuck in white until its fully added

without knowing more about the context its hard to say, but if there is a lot of data you probably want to let the default UI render first, then start loading the data.  You may also want to delay assigning the BindingContext until after the data is loaded

@Jason is their any sample code for that type of approach , because iam following an MVVM and iam using relative binding for the listitemsource.

there is nothing about this that is non "MVVM"

All you need is to use ObservableRangeCollection and there is method called AddRange. You can find such collection for example here https://github.com/MPowerKit/VirtualizeListView/blob/main/MPowerKit.VirtualizeListView/ObservableRangeCollection.cs
Note: that under the hood ObservableCollection and thus ObservableRangeCollection stores items in the List<T>, so there is no need to do the batch updates, even more, batching will only decrease your performance.
What I would do - is to parse json in the background thread and then call AddRange on the collection in the main thread.
But also you have to keep in mind what UI element is using this collection. If it BindableLayout, then it is unacceptable to use huge data sets there.
Before fetching and parsing data I would show some loader to the user, that he can understand that smth is happening now and he should wait a bit.

Thanks for the answer , my data is loading and showing into UI the same time i found out that adding to ObservableCollection and triggering the event wasnt the only issue but showing the Listview at the same time causes big impact , i tried to hide the UI on application load and a button to show the tasks list , this do create the slow or hand in application but still i can show some loading or splash screen smth is going on. Thanks once again
